# Angular distinctUntilChanged - Value comparison

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a stream of observable which is emitting from an input `on blur` using `fromEvent` operator, where I am trying to compare if the previous value and current value are not the same.

When the page loads for the first time there is no value in the input filed at that point it is still emitting a value of blank, How this can be prevented? It will emit value if the values are not same.

```
fromEvent(this.input.nativeElement, 'blur')
   .pipe(
        takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$),
        map((evt: any) => evt.target.value),
        distinctUntilChanged(
            (pre: any, curr: any) =>
            JSON.stringify(pre) === JSON.stringify(curr)
        )
    )
    .subscribe((caption: string) => {
        console.log('value)
    })
```

Comment: How about adding a filter for blank value?

Comment: @Ritesh, If a user already added a value and saved it, then came back again and blanked it. At that point is it going to work?

Comment: Your requirement is if it is blank it should not got to subscribe block right, if yes, it will always work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use skipWhile:

```
  fromEvent(this.input.nativeElement, 'blur')
  .pipe(
    takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$),
    map((evt: any) => evt.target.value),
    skipWhile((text, index) => index === 0 && text === ''),
    distinctUntilChanged(
      (pre: any, curr: any) => JSON.stringify(pre) === JSON.stringify(curr)
    )
  ).subscribe((caption: string) => {
    console.log(caption);
  });
```

Comment: First time it is not emitting if blank, but this condition is not satisfying `If a user already added a value and saved it, then came back again and blanked it.` What I can do about it?

Comment: Can you check this URL - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-d9j8x6?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: why  not use simply `distinctUntilChanged()`?. the response after the map is a "string", you needn't JSON.stringify